# Return a (math) function from a procedure/function?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB so bear with me.

I know we can return a function (in programming term) from a function (in programming term), but how do I return a (math) function from a MATLAB function?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I define my (math) function as followed:

```
coeffs = [1 2 3];
x = sym('x');
y = sym('y');
f(x, y) = coeffs(1) * x + coeffs(2) * y + coeffs(3);
```

Then I can use the function in my code like this:

```
val1 = f(1, 2);
val2 = f(2, 3);
```

This is all good. Now, my `f(x, y)` isn't always has this form `ax + by + c`, so I would like to create a (MATLAB) function that returns the appropriate form based on the input like this:

```
function retF = createFunction(someinput)
  % code here
  if (some condition)
     %retF =  f(x, y) = coeffs(1) * x + coeffs(2) * y + coeffs(3);
  else 
     %retF = f(x, y) = <sth else>;
  end
end
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions: you question appear to have nothing to do with building GUIs in Matlab, so I removed the [matlab-guide] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly return the function, no need to use two variable names:

```
function retF = createFunction(someinput)
  % code here
  if (some condition)
     retF(x, y) = coeffs(1) * x + coeffs(2) * y + coeffs(3);
  else 
     retF(x, y) = <sth else>;
  end
end
```